# Redirect response data to another view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

im trying in my controller method to pass some data to a order sucess page, information regarding the details of payment, but i cant make it work or pass the data.

In my case i wish for example pass this request

```
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;


            $response = $http->request('POST', 'https://domain', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'chave' => 'somekey',
                    'valor' => Cart::total(),
                    'id' => $order->id,

                ]
            ]);

            $result = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(),true);

            Cart::destroy();

            return redirect()->route('frontend-cart-success')->with( ['data' => $result] );
```

And then in my view sucess page just calling the $data Info to show on my blade file.

But i cant it ut it work.

My route to pass in sucess page:

```
Route::get('cart/success/', 'Frontend\CartController@showSuccess')->name('frontend-cart-success');
```

Best regards

Comment: Is there difference if you remove trailing slash from route url definition (i.e. `'/cart/success'`)?

Answer (score 0):

I code mostly in SPAs, but according to the API (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L42), it's flashing that data to the session, so you're going to have to get the data back out using the session.

See: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-to-route-with-data?page=1